# How to decrypt AES 256 https://aesencryption.net/ - IOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

Plain text : Encrypt and decrypt text with AES algorithm

Key (256)  : testsecret

Result (https://aesencryption.net/) : iFhSyFY3yYoO2G6GVGkdhZJjD+h0Pxv5fQnO3xIarzuGQSkIxlrpSprC5bC3gJ2U

i use small code in object to decrypt this this text :

> - (NSData*)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
>     // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
>     char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
>     bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
>
>   // fetch key data
>     [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
>   NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
>
>   //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
>     //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
>     //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
>     size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
>     void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);
>
>   size_t numBytesDecrypted    = 0; //    char iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1]; bzero(iv, sizeof(iv)) ;
>     CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding ,
>                                           keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
>                                           NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
>                                           [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
>                                           buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
>                                           &numBytesDecrypted);
>
>   if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
>     {
>         //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
>         return [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
>     }
>
>   free(buffer); //free the buffer;
>     return nil; }

Result : t\PFLFC\^X\^C^\^^\^RWQV\^\ypt text with AES algorithm

Seem it alway wrong first 16bit block. Can u help me. what i'm wrong when encrypt ?

Comment: Why the hell would you copy cryptographic code or test vectors from somebody that cannot even spell anything correctly and understands *nothing* about cryptography? Setting the blocksize of AES to 128, 192 or 256? Using a password instead of a key? What have they been drinking? Learn crypto first so you can *at least* distinguish between real and garbage like the code shown on that site.

Answer (score 1):

aesencryption.net performs AES in CBC mode. IV is a hardcoded ASCII string (16 chars). Message is UTF8-encoded then PKCS7-padded. AES key is the given password, UTF8-encoded then null-padded to choosen key size (or truncated if password is too long). And of course, the result is displayed as base64.
Getting the IV is as simple as encrypting a given block, decrypting it in ECB mode, and xoring that decrypted block with the original one...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AESCrypt-ObjC](https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC) instead of Cryptlib Library.

**Installation**

Add this line to your class:

```
#import "AESCrypt.h"
```

**Usage**

```
NSString *message = @"top secret message";
NSString *password = @"p4ssw0rd";
```

**Encrypting**

```
NSString *encryptedData = [AESCrypt encrypt:message password:password];
```

**Decrypting**

```
NSString *message = [AESCrypt decrypt:encryptedData password:password];
```

Hope this will help.

Also, you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51767050/5167909

Comment: I had try  AESCrypt-ObjC  and it alway return nil when decrypt. i had attack screent in this link: https://ibb.co/je5g7p

Comment: Would you please try to encrypt a sample message first and then again decrypt the encrypted message. Check what is happening.

Comment: If use encrypt - decrypt  of AESCrypt-ObjC  it work (original text -> encrypt plain text - decrypt - original text). But i want decrypt  result of page https://aesencryption.net/

Comment: I think the website used another library for encryption and decryption. Please check out my another answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51767050/5167909

Comment: I had try and fail  it can't decrypt result of  https://aesencryption.net/

Comment: https://aesencryption.net already provide the Java code for encrypting and decrypting a message in below.

Answer (score 0):

Your CCCryptorStatus parameters in osstatus : 
should look like this

`cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256 NULL,[self bytes], dataLength,  buffer, bufferSize,  &numBytesEncrypted );`,

However you length of the key is less than 16 bytes. At least make sure that your secret key should be of 16 bytes.